# Ember or coal metaphor regarding love

Tags: metaphors

In Russian, *ember* is used as a metaphor of something fading or dying (for example, love). Likewise, "*to make the ember burn again*" is a metaphor for bringing something back from near death.
Is there a similar metaphor specifically related to *coal* or *ember* in English?

Comment: If context is appropriate, the metaphor would be understood straight. If you reference "embers of love" or "of the heart", you can pretty much assume it will be clear.

Comment: A *phoenix* is often used to describe this in English, right? Coming back from the ashes. Not sure.

Answer (score 4):

"Respark an old flame", for example, or "rekindle an old flame". Both expressions are used to refer to restartig a romantic relationship with a specific someone you once loved.

Comment: You _rekindle an old flame_ with someone you were _carrying a torch for._